# Return the corresponding integer

Tags: scala

I need to write a recursive function that would return a corresponding integer from the given list. For example, list1 = List(2,3,1,7,5)
fromList(list1) would return 57132
This is what I have.

```
def fromList(list1: List[Int]): Int = {
    val num1 = list1.head
    val num2 = fromList(list1.tail)
    if (list1.isEmpty) num1
    else num1 + num2
  }
```

I'm able to solve this if I use power operation but this operation is limited.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
def fromList(list1: List[Int]): Int =
  list1.reverse.fold(0)(10 * _ + _)
  
fromList(List(2,3,6))  //res0: Int = 632
```

Can also be done with `foldRight()`.

```
def fromList(list1: List[Int]): Int =
  list1.foldRight(0)(_ + _ * 10)
```

---

If recursion is required...

```
@annotation.tailrec
def fromList(list1: List[Int], acc:Int = 0): Int =
  if (list1.isEmpty) acc
  else fromList(list1.init, 10*acc + list1.last)
  
fromList(List(2,3,6,1))  //res0: Int = 1632
```

Or the slightly more verbose but likely more efficient...

```
def fromList(list1: List[Int]): Int = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(lst: List[Int], acc:Int = 0):Int = lst match {
    case hd::tl => loop(tl, 10*acc + hd)
    case _ => acc
  }
  loop(list1.reverse, 0)
}

fromList(List(7,3,6,4))  //res0: Int = 4637
```

---

There are 2 major problems with your original design.

1st - Both `list1.head` and `list1.tail` are impossible if `list1.isEmpty`. So you need to test for that before decomposing the `List`.

2nd - You need to adjust the intermediate results before adding the current digit.

```
//recursive but not tail-recursive
def fromList(list1: List[Int]): Int =
  if (list1.isEmpty) 0
  else 10 * fromList(list1.tail) + list1.head
```

Comment: I really liked your solution but it has to be recursive

Answer (score 0):

@jwvh solution is recursive(tail) if you might want a non tail recursive though with a good chance of a stack overflow for large values then

```
def solution (list : List[Int]): Int = {
  def recursive(list1: List[Int]): Int= {
    list1 match {
      case head :: tail => head * scala.math.pow(10, list1.length-1).toInt + recursive(tail)
      case Nil => 0
    }
  }
  recursive(list.reverse)
}
```

Comment: Not only does this use a lot of stack, but it is `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n)` and uses `pow` rather than `*`. Why not `recurse(tail)*10 + head`?!

Answer (score 0):

Not recursive, but does the job :)

```
list1.reverse.mkString("").toInt
```